# Magento 2 static asset response code when static deployment is running

Tags: static-content, static-content-deploy

When you are generating static content and you view a link to an asset for example

`https://domain/static/version1234/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_GB/mage/translate.js`

If you view the file before it's been generated you see the following error

[image: Service Temporarily Available]

And a 404 response code is sent. Refresh after static content process is finished you see the asset and a 200 response code is sent. Does anyone know where the code that sends the  404 response code is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sooner had I posted the question I finally figured this out.

The store is on default mode.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/StaticResource.php#L163-L186

```
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function catchException(Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        $this->getLogger()->critical($exception->getMessage());
        if ($bootstrap->isDeveloperMode()) {
            $this->response->setHttpResponseCode(404);
            $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            $this->response->setBody(
                $exception->getMessage() . "\n" .
                Debug::trace(
                    $exception->getTrace(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    (bool)getenv('MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS')
                )
            );
            $this->response->sendResponse();
        } else {
            require $this->getFilesystem()->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::PUB)->getAbsolutePath('errors/404.php');
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So I'm hitting this part `require $this->getFilesystem()->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::PUB)->getAbsolutePath('errors/404.php');`

And checking errors/404.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.2/pub/errors/404.php#L11

`$response = $processor->process404();`

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/pub/errors/processor.php#L209-L220

```
    /**
     * Process 404 error
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
     */
    public function process404()
    {
        $this->pageTitle = 'Error 404: Not Found';
        $this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(404);
        $this->_response->setBody($this->_renderPage('404.phtml'));
        return $this->_response;
    }
```

This part `$this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(404);`